# Зачем нужны сессии hibernate?

Tags: java-ee, сессия, java, hibernate, база-данных

Здравствуйте.
Просмотрел весь интернет, но так и не нашел толкового объяснения, зачем нужны `Session` при работе с БД. Использлвал `Hibernate`. Какой смысл сессии?, вот к примеру использование транзакции более-менее понятно: выполняется запрос к БД, в случае корректного выполнения транзакция комитится, в случае ошибки производится откат.

Answer (score 2):

Гм. А вы пробовали в [документацию](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html) поглядеть? Там весьма доходчиво разъяснено, каково предназначение сессий.

Comment: Вы предложили ссылку на документацию на английском. Наш сайт - на русском. Уже хотя бы одно это говорит, что ваш "ответ" не к месту. Если не в состоянии дать нормальный ответ, лучше промолчите.

Answer (score 2):

Как-то Вы больно упростили работу хибернайта. В общем если без доки и на пальцах, да простят меня "мастодонты", все нижеописаное довольно грубо и не точно =)
На примере загрузки объекта:
В общем, мысль в том, что работая с хибернейтом Вы работаете с объектами, но вот в чем хрень, когда Вы работаете с объектом и если он "упихивается" в одну запись БД, то вроде все просто: тут строка, там число, но что делать если объект имеет связи, ссылается на другие хибернэйт объекты? Тащить весь граф объектов, вроде не рояль, накладно слишком, но а работать нужно, как же это происходит
В общем выгружая Ваш объект, хибернейт проксирует его, т.е. Вы получаете не свой исконный объект, а прокси, который при обращении к ссылочному полю, запрашивает его.
Так вот если у Вас нет сессии или Вы работаете в разных сессиях. то при попытке обратится к полю, которое является объектом хибернэйта, попросту словите lazy initialization